# Using ADSL Router With LAN Internet As Input

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet, adsl, adsl-router

> Can I use ADSL modem with Ethernet LAN?

The purpose was to broadcast `LAN wire internet` over WIFI.
By mistake,I bought ADSL router, it accepts `telephone jack input only as input internet`

Is there any tweak available for this?

**EDIT:**
I am planning to flash router software with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.co.in/site/index) to change the behavior of router.

1. Discard use of telephone jack.
2. Use one of four RJ-45 port for internet input.

Can some one please tell, in which mode modem should operate? client / client bridge / ad-hoc?

Comment: Your router needs to route the Internet traffic to and from your devices.  It can only route between it's LAN and WAN sides, so no, it won't work.  Take the router back and get one that is JUST a router (instead of a router/modem combo).

Comment: @techie007 that link says not it is not possible.

Comment: It sure does, and that's because it's not possible. :)

Comment: Why not just return it and get the correct type of device?